# I am trying to pass two classes into a method but getting a message saying "does not have a new() constraint?

Tags: c#

Here is a method that I have:

```
    private static Style<ShellContent> SetGlyph(string glyph)
    {
        return new Style<ShellContent>().Add(new Trigger(typeof(ShellContent))
        {
            Property = ShellContent.IsCheckedProperty,
            Value = true,
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter()
                {
                    Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                    Value = new RegularTabIcon() { Glyph = glyph }
                },
                new Setter()
                {
                    Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                    Value = new SolidTabIcon() { Glyph = glyph }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to change this so I can pass in the classes RegularTabIcon, SolidTabIcon and possibly change those to RegularTabIcon and ThinTabIcon.

Here is what the RegularTabIcon class looks like:

```
public class RegularTabIcon : FontImageSource
{
    public RegularTabIcon()
    {
        FontFamily = nameof(Fonts.FaProRegular);
        Size = 20;
    }
}
```

I tried to create a generic class like this:

```
    private static Style<ShellContent> SetGlyph<T1, T2>(string glyph)
    {
        return new Style<ShellContent>().Add(new Trigger(typeof(ShellContent))
        {
            Property = ShellContent.IsCheckedProperty,
            Value = true,
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter()
                {
                    Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                    Value = new T1() { Glyph = glyph }
                },
                new Setter()
                {
                    Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                    Value = new T2() { Glyph = glyph }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But I'm getting this error message next to new T1 and new T2

```
does not have a new() constraint
```

Can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong here?

Also how can I specify that T1 and T2 must be of type `FontImageSource`?

Comment: I updated my answer. I did answer your last question (Also how can I specify that T1 and T2 must be of type FontImageSource?)

Comment: The error message seems perfectly clear to me. See duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the `new()` constraint to method's constaint.

Try this:

```
private static Style<ShellContent> SetGlyph<T1, T2>(string glyph) where T1 : new() where T2 : new()
{
    return new Style<ShellContent>().Add(new Trigger(typeof(ShellContent))
    {
        Property = ShellContent.IsCheckedProperty,
        Value = true,
        Setters =
        {
            new Setter()
            {
                Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                Value = new T1() { Glyph = glyph }
            },
            new Setter()
            {
                Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                Value = new T2() { Glyph = glyph }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> The new constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class
> declaration must have a public parameterless constructor.

For the more details about `new()` constraint, you can visit this link : [new constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

**UPDATED: 03.05.2021**

If you want `T1` and `T2` must be of type `FontImageSource` also, you can add type constraint to method constraints like as below:

```
private static Style<ShellContent> SetGlyph<T1, T2>(string glyph) where T1 : FontImageSource, new() where T2 : FontImageSource, new()
{
    return new Style<ShellContent>().Add(new Trigger(typeof(ShellContent))
    {
        Property = ShellContent.IsCheckedProperty,
        Value = true,
        Setters =
                {
                    new Setter()
                    {
                        Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                        Value = new T1() { Glyph = glyph }
                    },
                    new Setter()
                    {
                        Property = ShellContent.IconProperty,
                        Value = new T2() { Glyph = glyph }
                    }
                }
    });
}
```

**Note:** If you use both `new()` and type constraint (for example: `FontImageSource`), `new()` constraint must be located end of the others constraints. When you use the `new()` constraint with other constraints, it must be specified last.

For the more details about constraints on type parameters, you can visit this link : [Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)